# How to write easyMock.expect for int[]

Tags: java, unit-testing, reflection, easymock

Throwing error Targetinvocationexception.

```
public class A{
      public method_name(){
      int[] selections = grid.getSelectedIndices(); // Facing issue here...!
      // Problem occur above line.
      }
}

public class A_test{
    Grid grid = EasyMock.createNicemock(Grid.class);
    EasyMock.expect(grid.getSelectedIndices().andReturn(EasyMock.arEq(new int[] {1})));
    EasyMock.replay(grid);    

// I able to invoke method with the help of reflection
// method.invoke();
}
```

Question: I am not able to expect on "getSelectedIndices()".
At some changes it give me error of 0 matcher and 1 reported. As cannot able to match mock object and raw value

Answer (score 0):

The [andReturn](http://easymock.org/user-guide.html#verification-return) method takes the return value as argument, but [EasyMock.aryEq](http://easymock.org/user-guide.html#verification-expectations) returns null (see the [Source](https://github.com/easymock/easymock/blob/d044d74048c19c9db3aa9a0583e176cadbeef4f3/core/src/main/java/org/easymock/EasyMock.java#L1566)). You can just use `.andReturn(new int[] {1})` instead `.andReturn(EasyMock.arEq(new int[] {1})))`.

Answer (score 0):

Similar to the other answer. The way it works is that you expect arguments by matching them and if it's a match, you return a value. So the code should be.

```
public class A_test {
    Grid grid = niceMock(Grid.class);
    expect(grid.getSelectedIndices()).andReturn(new int[] {1});
    replay(grid);    

    A a = new A(grid);
    a.method_name(); 
}
```